# I am trying to create an upload file button, but whenever I try and use a file I get the error "Empty path name is not legal"

Tags: c#

Every time I click on a file, I get the error

> Empty path name is not legal

I need a user to upload a `.txt` or `.csv` file and have the contents of that file to display in the data grid view. Everything works fine except for this one error that occurs on this line:

```
var sr = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);
```

Full code.

```
private void selectButton_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        try
        {
            var sr = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            SetText(sr.ReadToEnd());
        }
        catch (SecurityException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"Security error.\n\nError message{ex.Message}\n\n" +
                $"Details:\n\n{ex.StackTrace}");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add filter on openFileDialog1 like.

```
openFileDialog1.Filter = "text file(*.txt)|*.txt|csv file(*.csv)|*.csv";
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the FileName before open file:

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(openFileDialog1.FileName) {
            // ..
            return; 
        }

        try
        {
            var fileStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile();

            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
            {
                SetText(sr.ReadToEnd());
            }       
        }
        catch (SecurityException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"Security error.\n\nError message{ex.Message}\n\n" +
                $"Details:\n\n{ex.StackTrace}");
        }
    }
```